# iOS updates and iCloud

Tags: icloud, ios

I can't remember what happens when I update my iOS: will I be asked for my iCloud password? I would like to delete my iCloud account ultimately and I guess if i didn't have an account I wouldn't be asked for the password after updating my iOS but just wondered if I will be asked while my account is active.

Comment: Every app & service including the phone activation itself is associated with the Apple ID that was initially used. You cannot dissociate one from the other by 'deleting' an account. Additionally, accounts themselves cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You will be asked for your *Apple ID* and *Password*.  Often, this is the same thing as your *iCloud* account but it doesn't have to be.  If you run into problems, you can contact Apple for assistance.

You can follow [these instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204204) for how to update your iOS device.